# Binding to a list of Custom Objects and Displaying in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

So i'm creating a list of custom objects and I want to display those in a carousel view.

for ex:

```
class report
{
   public string name;
   public string id;
   public DateTime dateTime;
}
```

and in xamarin I want to create a carousel that displays the name and ID of each report made

xaml:

```
<CarouselView x:Name="ReportCarouselView">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <!-- this is where I need help-->
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

c#:

```
var reports = new List<Report>
            {
                new Report{ name = "foo1", id = "id1"},
                new Report{ name = "foo2", id = "id2"},
                new Report{ name = "foo3", id = "id3"},

            };

ReportCarouselView.ItemsSource = reports;
```

how can I make it so that within the DataTemplate>StackLayout, I can display the name and ID of each report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, your class needs to have **public properties** for binding to work

```
public class report
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string id { get; set; }
   public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
}
```

then in your XAML

```
<CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
      <Label Text="{Binding id}" />
    </StackLayout>
  </DataTemplate>
</CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```